# Selected image from Gallery but it doesnt show in my image button

Tags: android, image, gallery

I'm making a function which is when I select "Choose from gallery" in an alert dialog box, the selected image inside gallery will appear in the imagebutton. I don't know what's wrong with my code. 
I used these website as an example to do it http://geekonjava.blogspot.sg/2014/03/upload-image-on-server-in-android-using.html and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/capture-image-from-camera-and-selecting-image-from-gallery-o/ . There isn't any code errors or logcat errors. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
public static class CardFrontFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

        private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    private String uploadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath = null;
    private ImageButton upload;


    public CardFrontFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.card_front, container, false);

         upload = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.fileUpload);

        upload.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadServerUri = Constants.serverUrl + "api/FileUpload";

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0 == upload)
        {

            selectImage();

        }

    } 

     private void selectImage() {

            final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    }
                    else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                    }
                    else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            upload.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }   

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

}
```

And these are the permissions that i have declared in androidmanifest.xml :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Try to log `selectedImageUri` and `imagepath` variables. What are the values of these vars?

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating your imagebutton. That way you tell the UI that it should be redrawn, because a value changed.

Comment: Is this what u trying to say? 
' upload = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.fileUpload);
  upload.invalidate();'

Comment: Yes, invalidate is telling the view that something has changed, and it needs to be redrawn. Try it out and let me know how it went. Here is some more info on invalidate ==> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html ( search for invalidate )

Comment: Yes, i tried this.
'upload = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.fileUpload); upload.invalidate();'
it doesnt work :(

Comment: Owh :( I'll try to recreate your project in a little sample app, and see for myself, i'll keep you updated. If you find a solution, let me know too :)

Comment: I tried to put all the codes outside of the fragment. and the selected image from gallery is able to be shown. Thus, i guess the problem is the fragment.

Comment: In other words, onActivityResult didn't executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `onActivityResult` to

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        upload.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
    }
}
```